# Wrong CSS positioning with Chrome/Edge when using columns

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Yesterday I discovered a layout issue with Chrome and Edge that doesn't show up in the Samsung Internet Browser and didn't exist before. The problem only occurs when using columns. Here's my CSS:

```
.div_columns {
    width:500px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

.card {
    height: 32px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.div_buttons {
    position: relative;
    height: 34px;
    min-width: 50px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #808080;
    padding-top: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;  
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="div_columns">
  <div class="card"><div class="div_buttons"><div class="button"></div></div></div>
  <div class="card"><div class="div_buttons"><div class="button"></div></div></div>
  <div class="card"><div class="div_buttons"><div class="button"></div></div></div>
  <div class="card"><div class="div_buttons"><div class="button"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

The output looks like this, and as you can see there appears to be only one button instead of four. But they all appear to be in the same position. Like I said at the start, this problem seems to be browser and use of columns related. So what is wrong here?

[image]

Another annoying thing I want to mention is that when I use Microsoft Edge's developer tools (F12) and want to copy a CSS rule by right-clicking, the developer tools close after that. This has not happened with Edge before and is not happening with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully restored these buttons to regular position by adding `display:inline-block` to the `div_columns` class.

As to the copy rule issue, I found it in my devtools, too. The only conclusion I've got is that if you right-click inside the braces `{}`, the context menu looks like below. The "Copy rule" option here works as expected:

[image]

But if you right-click outside the braces, the context menu changes like below. The "Copy rule" option here will lead to a crash of devtools (actually any option here will lead to a crash). But what's more interesting is that the style rule will still be on your clipboard. So I suggest sending a feedback to Edge team by pressing **Shift+Alt+I** in Edge:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I am still interested to know if Chrome/Edge follow the specifications with this positioning issue. As for the 'Copy rule' thing: I was indeed clicking outside the braces, on top of the class name. I will send feedback to the Edge Team.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this i would just try to disable `position relative` `position absolute` and `float right`, and ill write something inside the buttons

i'd disable evrything till i find whats the problem

Comment: I know there are better ways to do this now (by using the flex container), but that does not alter the fact that browsers should display this page properly.

Comment: if you think it's a browser related problem you're supposed to change the code to adapt to any browser. 

I don't know if you can do something else

Comment: It also worked well with Chrome and Edge. I will change it, if it turns out not to be a bug.